# Append certain values to a dataset based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two datasets. I would like to append columns that contain certain values to one of the datasets based on specific matching criteria.

**Data**

***df1***

```
source  pw  count   date    leaving
aa      20  2       q122    
aa      10  1       q322    
                
        6   2       q422    bb
```

***df2***

```
id  date    other   
aa  q1 22   1   
aa  q2 22   1   
aa  q3 22   1   
bb  q1 22   1   
bb  q2 22   11  
bb  q3 22   2   
bb  q4 22   2
```

**Desired**

```
id  date    other   source  pw  count   date    leaving
aa  q1 22   1       aa      20  2       q122
aa  q2 22   1               
aa  q3 22   1       aa      10  1       q322
bb  q1 22   1               
bb  q2 22   11              
bb  q3 22   2               
bb  q4 22   2               6   2       q422    bb

        
Logic 
Append the source column to df2 if the source column value matches the id column as well if the date column in df1 matches the date column in df2. 

Same logic with the 'leaving' column
```

**Doing**

possible mapping

```
df2['source']=df2['aa'].map({
'q1 22':'' })
```

concat

```
pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: I think you can have problem later if you have 2 columns with the same name. How do you solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way:

```
df1['id'] = df1['source'].combine_first(df1['leaving'])
df1['date'] = df1['date'].apply(lambda s: f'{s[:2]} {s[2:]}')

out = df2.merge(df1, on=['id', 'date'], how='outer')
```

```
>>> out.fillna('')
   id   date  other source    pw count leaving
0  aa  q1 22      1     aa  20.0   2.0
1  aa  q2 22      1
2  aa  q3 22      1     aa  10.0   1.0
3  bb  q1 22      1
4  bb  q2 22     11
5  bb  q3 22      2
6  bb  q4 22      2          6.0   2.0      bb
```

Comment: yes - thank you I will only have one 'date' column in the final output - I will try

Comment: What exactly is the lambda function doing here? df1['date'] = df1['date'].apply(lambda s: f'{s[:2]} {s[2:]}')

Comment: This rewrites the column `date` of df1 to match the column `date` of df2. `q122` becomes `q1 22` with a whitespace between `q1` and `22`. If your two date columns match, you can omit the 2nd line.

Comment: Ahhh ok yes I think this is what confused me - but I know you put this based on my post! Thanks